# JavaScript - Can't get the input field

Tags: javascript, login-page

This is my code for my login page:
http://pastebin.com/RGVrW0Hi

It's the field right under the `body` tag.

All the way down there is a scipt tag with my function. I'm trying to check if the user has typed something inside the "Navn" field, if not it should return `false`.

I have tried it in a smaller page that look like this:
http://pastebin.com/d1vzyDvd

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please include only relevant code in your question. Links to code are not good here, especially when it's a 500+ line file.

Comment: First thing: move your js right before the closing body tag, not after.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get any field by name use

```
var value = document.getElementsByName("navn")[0].value;
// By Id
var value = document.getElementsById("navn").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementsByName("navn").value[0]` instead of `document.famular.navn.value` to get the value of an input field by its name.

```js
function validerform125() {

  if (document.getElementsByName("navn")[0].value == "") {
    alert("NEEEJ!!!");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="famular" action="vanillahost.html" method="post" onsubmit="return validerform125()">
  Navn
  <input name="navn" type="text">
  <br/>Email
  <input name="email" type="email">
  <br/>

  <div>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="send">
  </div>
</form>
```

You add `[0]` to `document.getElementsByName("navn")` because `getElementsByName` returns a NodeList object which represents a collection of elements with the specified name (In your case: `"Navn"`). By adding [0] you are basically returning the first element found.

Answer (score 0):

better if you can include jquery in your html, will give you a nicer interface to interact with html elements.

In java-script you can try the following code

```html
<body>
<div>
    <form name="famular" action="vanillahost.html" method="post" onsubmit="return validerform125()">
        Navn <input name="navn" type="text"><br/>
        Email <input name="email" type="email"><br/>

        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="send" value="send">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
<script>
   function validerform125() {
    var x = document.forms["famular"]["navn"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
   } 
</script>
```

Comment: I hope it will help you :).